# Windows 10 IoT File System

Tags: raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I am currently searching for a way to interact with external USB devices, such as hard drives or USB sticks.

I want to interact with the files on these USB devices from my apps.

Since it is .NetCore you can't use System.IO for that.

Any Ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) in UWP API. Here's a [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188699.aspx)